# Hollow-box star pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

In this problem, what is the role of `print()` at the last? and why its affecting the code output if not included?

```
n = int(input("Enter the number: "))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if(i==0 or i==n-1 or j==0 or j==n-1):
            print("*", end=' ')
        else:
            print(" ", end=' ')
    print()
```

**Output: For a number (Say '3')**

without `print()` -

```
* * * *   * * * *
```

with `print()` -

```
* * * 
*   * 
* * *
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You'll get a much better response if you show what you've tried so far. For example, what does the `print()` function do? What does it do when called without parameters like this? How does the output differ if you don't include it? Good luck with your studies, and enjoy learning Python!

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis , thank you fo your kind suggestion.. I have edited the question and have added the results

Comment: Great! So, what do you think the line `print()` does? What is the difference between the two outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are printing asterisks or spaces with:

```
print("*", end=' ')
```

and

```
print("", end=' ')
```

those print statements are not advancing a line due to the "end=' '" bit.  That is why you get either an asterisk or space printing one after another.  The line of code:

```
print()
```

isn't actually printing anything, but it is sending a carriage return and line feed to advance to the next line.  So if you have a print statement that does not include the "end=' '" directive, your terminal output will advance to the next line.